# methods in onCreate() not found

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
        "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        R.layout.activity_main, FRUITS));
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The following errors appear:

```
Gradle: cannot find symbol method
setListAdapter(android.widget.ArrayAdapter<java.lang.String>)
Gradle: cannot find symbol method getListView()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code starts with:

> public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Since you are using getListView() you must extend ListActivity instead. Try

> public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

Comment: @sagarlakhani62: Then you have more problems than that. Does your ListView in activity_main.xml has android:id="@id/android:list"?

Comment: i try to this code first method of this page                    http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: Have you tried commenting out setContentView? You haven't in the question but the example has.

Answer (score 0):

You should **extend** `ListActivity` instead of `Activity`. And your problem should be long gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
 ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FRUITS));

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample listactivity code, changing it according to your need:

File : res/layout/list_fruit.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

File: ListFruitActivity.java

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListFruitActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
            "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
            "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // no more this
        // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit,FRUITS));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **extend** ListActivity instead of Activity and in your xml  listview id must be

```
    android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Extend `ListActivity` instead of only `Activity`.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity { }
   ```
2. In your `R.layout.activity_main` use `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"/>`
3. Create an adapter for list.(following is just an example to explain.)

   ```
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,  // Context.
               ndroid.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // Specify the row template to use
               your_array);    // your array having data
   ```
4. `setListAdapter(arrayAdapter );`